# Why smallint is automatically inserting 0 when passing null persistent object without initialization that has primitve data type

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, postgresql-9.3

I am using PostgreSQL Plus Advance Server 9.3 and hibernate3 in my Java code. So today I got this problem when I was storing an object value into database.

This is a main class with all setters and getters (but I did not write them):

```
public class Job {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private JobActivation jobActivation;
}
```

And this is second  class:-

```
public class JobActivation {

    private int numChecks;
    private int expiryInMinutes;
    private int checksIntervalInMinutes;
    private boolean isMultiple;
}
```

And DataBase Code for this is:

```
CREATE TABLE job
(
  id integer,
  name character varying(20),
  checks_expiry integer DEFAULT 0,
  num_checks integer DEFAULT 0,
  checks_interval integer DEFAULT 0,
  is_multiple_activation smallint DEFAULT false
)
```

And the hibernate configuration code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.test.job">
<class name="Job" table="JOB">
<id name="id" column="id">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="name"/>
 <component name="jobActivation" class="JobActivation">
            <property name="expiryInMinutes" column="CHECKS_EXPIRY"/>
            <property name="numChecks" column="NUM_CHECKS"/>
            <property name="isMultiple" access="field" column="IS_MULTIPLE_ACTIVATION"/>
            <property name="checksIntervalInMinutes" column="CHECKS_INTERVAL"/>
        </component>
</class>   
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now the problem is when I am creating an object of Job class and only setting all values of all variables of Job class only means JobActivation object is null in that case and storing the object persistant object using hibernate like:-

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setName("Job1");
try{
        session.save(job);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

then what is happening is...
values that is storing in database is:-

```
Columns "id"|"name"|"checks_expiry"|"num_checks"|"checks_interval"|"is_multiple_activation"
Values    1   Job1      _                 _            _                0
```

even when I removed default value = 0 from database then also the same result is returned. Then I traced hibernate query with value that is-

```
insert into JOB (name, CHECKS_EXPIRY, NUM_CHECKS, IS_MULTIPLE_ACTIVATION, CHECKS_INTERVAL, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)|insert into JOB (name, CHECKS_EXPIRY, NUM_CHECKS, IS_MULTIPLE_ACTIVATION, CHECKS_INTERVAL, id) values ('Job1', '', '', '', '', 1)
```

Description of cmd of psql is:

```
test=# \d+ job
                                         Table "public.job"
         Column         |         Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                     | integer               |           | plain    |              |
 name                   | character varying(20) |           | extended |              |
 checks_expiry          | integer               | default 0 | plain    |              |
 num_checks             | integer               | default 0 | plain    |              |
 checks_interval        | integer               | default 0 | plain    |              |
 is_multiple_activation | smallint              |           | plain    |              |
Has OIDs: no
```

and when I just changed the smallint datatype to int or boolean in database then it is working fine - meaning not inserting any values that is expected result.
So I wanted to know that what exactly is the problem? Is there problem on hibernate side or Java code side or from database side and what is the solution for that?

Comment: Why don't you use a real `boolean` data type in the database? `is_multiple_activation boolean DEFAULT false`. Using the literal `false` for a `smallint` column doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah you are right but as we are using smallint in our whole project so we can not change it to boolean at one place.

Answer (score 1):

Because in java all fields (object variables) with primitive type always has default value. For `boolean` it is always `false`, what is interpreted as `0` for numeric type. If you want to store there `null` you should change its field's type to `Boolean`:

```
private Boolean isMultiple;
```

**UPD**: you should also remove `DEFAULT false` for `is_multiple_activation` table field from create-table-sql code, because it means, that this value is always `false` by default, i.e. it always has `0` value by default.

Comment: thanks for your input, are you talking about field changing in database? sorry  i don't want to change field type from database. i want to use smallint for boolean type in java.

Comment: I'm talking about changing type in java class, see my update of my answer above

Comment: it is already of boolean type. can you recheck again? i have already written.

Comment: @Krishna there are two similar types in java: `boolean` (with small letter `b` in the start) and `Boolean` (with capical letter `B` in the start). I think you should read java basic tutorials before doing something with jdbc and hibernate.

Comment: thanks but i changed to Boolean and check getting same output in database.

Comment: @Krishna, see my update: you should also remove `DEFAULT false` for `is_multiple_activation`

Comment: sorry! did the same as you said but not getting desired output.

Comment: @Krishna did you recompiled your project, deleted old version of the table?

Comment: yeah, but getting the same output

Comment: No i am doing right, i just changed the datatype from boolean to Boolean and then remove the default value from database and delete table and recreate. Is there anything missing?

Comment: Please, open `psql` console, connect to your database and provide the result of `\d+ job` command (description of `job` table).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59334/discussion-between-krishna-and-andremoniy).